# Как получить выбранный контакт?

Tags: android, android-intent

Вызываю activity со списком контактов

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Далее я должен выбрать контакт и в `startActivityForResult` он мне должен вернутся.
Но проблема в том, что я еще ничего не выбрал, а мне уже возвращается первый контакт.

```
@Override
public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
    super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        Uri contactData = intent.getData();
        Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {

            String phoneNumber = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

        }
    }
}
```

Как исправить данное поведение? Чтобы результат возвращался после того как я выберу контакт?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не очень опытен, но, по-моему, результат возвращается посредством переопределения метода onActivityResult, а вы переопределяете метод startActivityForResult

Comment: И в правду, моя не внимательность(